# Plotting the same function with different parameters

Tags: plotting

How can I plot the same function with different parameters?

I want to get something like this:

```
For[i = 0, i < 4, i++, Show[Plot[Sin[x] + i, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]]].
```

This is just an example.

Answer (score 7):

This is an alternative, perhaps more convenient depending on what you want to do with plot.

```
Plot[Evaluate[Sin[x] + # & /@ list], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 7}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> 
 LineLegend[Automatic,LegendFunction -> (Framed[#1, FrameMargins -> 0]&)]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `Table`,

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[Sin[x] + i, {i, 1, 6}], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {0, 7}]
```

[image]

Or use `SetDelay` plus `Range`,

```
f[i_] := Sin[x] + i

Plot[Evaluate[f /@ Range[6]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {0, 7}]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use mapping instead of a for loop:

For instance, define the list of parameter to be changed:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

Then:

```
Show[Plot[Sin[x] + #, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {0, 7}] & /@ list]
```

[image]

Have a look at how mapping works: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html

It is very useful to write clean code.